# can't access some WordPress function from my plugin

Tags: plugin-development, functions, include

I'm trying to write a relatively simple plugin. I have two php files, one is included within the other like this:

```
define( 'PLUGIN_DIR', dirname(__FILE__).'/' );
include_once(PLUGIN_DIR . '/included_file.php');
```

Things look fine. However I'm getting errors when I try to call some wordpress functions from within the included file:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined
>   function xxx() ...

The odd this is, only on some functions but not others. For example, if I place this code at the top of the included file:

```
if (!function_exists('add_action')) echo "<h1>add_action not found</h1>";
if (!function_exists('check_admin_referer')) echo "<h1>check_admin_referer not found</h1>";
if (!function_exists('wp_verify_nonce')) echo "<h1>wp_verify_nonce not found</h1>";
if (!function_exists('wp_nonce_field')) echo "<h1>wp_nonce_field not found</h1>";
```

I get this output:

```
check_admin_referer not found
wp_verify_nonce not found
```

so only two out of these four functions are accessible in the included file...

I'm probably missing something very basic, but I'm a bit stuck.

UPDATE: I tried creating a very basic plugin:

```
<?php
/*
    Plugin Name: Test this
    Plugin URI: http://www.gingerlime.com
    Description: test
    Author: Yoav Aner
    Version: 1.0
    Requires at least: 3.1
    Author URI: http://blog.gingerlime.com
    License: GPL 2.0, @see http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html

*/
if (!function_exists('add_action')) echo "<h1>add_action not found</h1>";
if (!function_exists('check_admin_referer')) echo "<h1>check_admin_referer not found</h1>";
if (!function_exists('wp_verify_nonce')) echo "<h1>wp_verify_nonce not found</h1>";
if (!function_exists('wp_nonce_field')) echo "<h1>wp_nonce_field not found</h1>";
if (function_exists('add_action')) echo "<h1>add_action found</h1>";
if (function_exists('check_admin_referer')) echo "<h1>check_admin_referer found</h1>";
if (function_exists('wp_verify_nonce')) echo "<h1>wp_verify_nonce found</h1>";
if (function_exists('wp_nonce_field')) echo "<h1>wp_nonce_field found</h1>";
?>
```

as soon as the plugin is activated it prints

> check_admin_referer not found
>
> wp_verify_nonce not found
>
> add_action found
>
> wp_nonce_field found

I tried it on two wordpress installations. I might try a completely fresh wordpress and see what's going on. Strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, since the `if (!function_exists('check_admin_referer')) echo "<h1>check_admin_referer not found</h1>";` code is working, then you've eliminated the issue being proper including of your Plugin sub-file.

Second, all four of those functions are *core WordPress functions*, so you should *never* get a `call to undefined function` error for any of them. Can you post your relevant Plugin code, so we can see what's going on?

**EDIT**

My best guess is that certain functions aren't available until certain *actions* within the WordPress processing sequence.

Try hooking your function into `init`, or `admin_init`, and see if the errors disappear.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Chip. I checked further and this seems to happen from both files, so it's probably not an include issue either... See update above. Any ideas?

Comment: Updated my answer with a guess as to the cause.

Comment: Good guess Chip !! Thanks. I still find it a bit strange for wordpress to work this way, but hooking into admin_init seemed to have done the trick!

Comment: Glad it worked! For future reference, *all* Plugin code should ideally be hooked *explicitly* somewhere into the WordPress sequence, so that code is executed deliberately, wherever it is intended to execute.